# Postgresql : noInherit not working?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration

So, I'm trying to figure out how to properly administer a postgresql database.
I'm new with postgres and DBA in general.

I'm currently trying to have a dedicated role for a specific database.
I also want to have other user with a grant on that role so that I could do `SET ROLE my_db_role` and be able to manipulate this specific database from there.
However, I've got permission leakage, meaning that I can manipulate my database without having to do this `SET ROLE my_db_role` command.

Here are  the commands I do to get my unssuccessful result :

```
=# CREATE ROLE test NOINHERIT;
=# CREATE USER myuser;
=# CREATE DATABASE test OWNER test;
=# \c test
=# DROP SCHEMA public;
=# CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION test;
=# GRANT test TO myuser;
=# \c test myuser
=> CREATE TABLE test.mytable(id integer);
CREATE TABLE
Temps : 46,469 ms
```

Why did the last commands succeeded ?

In my opinion, myuser should have no right on test database/schema, as test role has the NOINHERIT flag, so this CREATE command should not be possible.
It should need to do `SET ROLE test` to succeed which is not the case here.

What am I missing ?

*On a side note, I have a hard time finding good source of information on how to administer properly postgresql apart from the official doc. If you can share some good material about it, you're more than welcome.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't know of any particularly good resource covering role management and administration. The standards here show all the signs of having to please several stake-holders and are flexible but confusing.

As to your immediate question though, the issue is that the "NOINHERIT" is on the wrong role. However, this feature is not really a security constraint.

```
test=# ALTER USER myuser NOINHERIT;
test=# \c - myuser
You are now connected to database "test" as user "myuser".
test=> CREATE TABLE test.mytable(id int);
ERROR:  permission denied for schema test
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE test.mytable(id int);
                     ^
test=> SET ROLE test;
SET
test=> CREATE TABLE test.mytable(id int);
CREATE TABLE
```

As you can see, `myuser` doesn't inherit the permissions of `test` but there is nothing to stop you switching directly to that role.

If you find this fiddly and confusing, then you are far from alone. I find it useful to add some [tests](http://pgtap.org/) to check any configuration I set up.

Comment: Awww! Thanks, I was indeed missing something :) Well, I'm not using this feature for security reason, but more to have some consistency in the tables and objects' owner under a particular database, as it "did not feel right" to me to have a table owned by a random user when the database is owned by another one. Thanks for the tests suggestion, I'm not there yet, but I will keep that in the back of my head...

Answer (score 1):

Because `test` is the owner of the database, it basically have all privileges on it on its subsequent objects.

As pointed out by @Richard Huxton setting `NOINHERIT` on `test` role prevent it to inherit form other roles, but does not prevent its privileges to be inherited to another roles.

When you issue:

```
GRANT test TO myuser;
```

You just grant the same privileges as the owner to `myuser`, therefore `myuser` can create object, actually it can do whatever the owner can.

It is not an issue of PostgreSQL it is the way ownership works. Anyway you can explicitly revoke privileges from owner (eg. not destroying an important object by mistake).

But you should consider other Privileges Policies for the role `myuser`, making it not inheriting from the owner but granting what it needs only. If the user can create a table, it should be blessed with:

```
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA test TO myuser;
```

I understand you are bit disappointed with PostgreSQL Privileges Management, at the very begging it can seem hard to understand through the documentation. To better learn how it actually works, you should issue:

```
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE test FROM public;
```

Then all roles will need explicit privileges to `CONNECT` and `SCHEMA USAGE`. You will then discover the dependencies between objects and privileges. Reading more and more the [`GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) page should be enough even if it is succinct.

About the [`SET ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-set-role.html) security "issue", it is limited to all roles the current role is member of:

> The specified role_name must be a role that the current session user
>   is a member of. (If the session user is a superuser, any role can be
>   selected.)

Therefore an user cannot override its privileges, it just can endorse other identity it has been granted with.

Comment: I don't want `myuser` to directly create a table because I want to avoid mixing ownership as I have the feeling it would bring some sort of complication (just a feeling). Here `myuser` would typically be an admin for the database. I could have another user that only have edit capability (Select, update, insert, delete) and another only able to read (Select).

Comment: Then do not make it inherits from the owner and just grant DML (SELECT, ...) to myuser. It will able to manipulate data without having the privilege to alter data structure.